# Launch default SMS app without a message

Tags: android, android-intent, text, sms, message

I am wanting my app to, on a button click, launch the user's default texting app. The intention is not to have the user send a message, but to view their current text conversations, therefore I don't want it to launch the SMS app's "New Message" activity but instead the main app's activity itself.

If I do the following:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Then this is launched, instead I want it to launch the main part of the app, not this new message screen:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

    startActivity(intent);
```

This may be what you want.

Comment: It looks like this method also works :-) Tested on Android 5.0.1 on Galaxy S4

Comment: THis only works if they use that particular SMS app.  Which is far form universal, even if they didn't download one they like better

Answer (score 16):

```
  String defaultApplication = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "sms_default_application");
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(defaultApplication );
        if (intent != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: It looks like this works :-) Tested on Android 5.0.1 on Galaxy S4

Comment: Thank you. Your solution has helped me to open default SMS-application without creating new message on Android 8.

Answer (score 2):

After a long search, this is what I ended up using:

```
String defaultSmsPackage = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT
    ? Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this)
    : Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "sms_default_application");

Intent smsIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(defaultSmsPackage);

if (smsIntent == null) {
    smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
}

try {
    startActivity(smsIntent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Could not open SMS app", e);

    // Inform user
    Toast.makeText(
        this,
        "Your SMS app could not be opened. Please open it manually.",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show();
}
```

It supports version KitKat and above. Below that it only supports apps that accept the `vnd.android-dir/mms-sms` intent. In case it is impossible to open the app, the user should be notified.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
String number = "12346556";  // The number on which you want to send SMS  
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null)));
```