# is it possible to open default messaging app by clicking link(hyperlink)?

Tags: android

I want to make link (hyperlink) that opens the mobile's default messaging app with "To : my number". 
(for eg. - I shared the link in some social media group and when anyone clicks on this link then he should be redirected to his mobiles default messaging app (built-in)).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471461/launch-default-sms-app-without-a-message/30471798

Comment: Do you mean how to format a link? Or create an Android app?

Comment: no no...no application.